# Self referencing model - product with list of products

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently working on a web api that handles the ordering of products by customers, namely closets.

Each product, among attributes like price, dimensions and category, has a list of products that it belongs to and another list of products that make up this particular product.

I'm seeing this as a self referencing model and as such wrote this first draft for a model class

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Height {get ; set; }
        public double Width {get ; set; }
        public double Depth {get ; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Parts{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> PartIn{ get; set; }
    }
```

Is this a correct approach? Especially considering that later on I need to make these calls

```
api/Product/{id}/Parts
api/Product/{id}/PartIn
```

that returns all the parts of one product and the products it is in.

Comment: I am a bit surprised about the three close votes. But I guess it is because of the "Is this the correct approach?". Maybe you should change this into "What are the advantages and disadvantages of this approach?".

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a good approach. The only issue I see is that you have redundant information by storing both the parents and the children. This will make updates more difficult. If for example you replace a child entry you have to make sure to update the corresponding parent entries in both the old and the new child product.

The alternative would be to only store either a list of child or parent products. This means that if you only strore the children, you need to perform a search through all products to get the parents of a given product.